# What is making Lotus Domino duplicate files?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Recently, a lot of files (forms, views, script libraries) began appearing in our databases in the following form:

aCertainForm(9C8D9154E5C13C5C83257ED0005FC0FE).form
aCertainForm(9C8D9154E5C13C5C83257ED0005FC0FE).form.metadata

Where aCertainForm.form (and its metadata) is a file that exists.
The files are often the same thing, so I usually delete them, but now some of them are starting to look different from the original and some of the originals are disappearing. Inside the Designer, they simply show up as duplicates.

What could be causing this? It may be useful to now that we recently started an experiment in using Git with our databases.

Comment: That Git experiment - it seems you or some other designer misconfigured on-disk project synchronization.

Comment: And what is the situation that's making this arise? What can we do about it?

Comment: Hard to tell.Need more info. Maybe it happens with conflict merges.

Answer (score 0):

We had that as well, but I cannot remember what caused it. Could it be that someone with an older installation recently replicated again, after many months without replication? You could have a look in the Navigator view of the (Eclipse) Designer.